# Group By - Return IEnumerable of only unique elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a LINQ to Entities query that I need to return only the unique instances of "ProgramYears", so that I can loop through them in my view.  I'm not sure how to alter this so that I'm not getting duplicates.

```
var data = from SurveyProgramModel in surveyProgramRepository.Get()
                       where SurveyProgramModel.ProgramYear == ProgramYear
                       group SurveyProgramModel by SurveyProgramModel.ProgramTypeId into programTypeGroup
           select new ProgramTypeViewModel()
           {

               ProgramTypeIds = programTypeGroup.Key,
               ProgramIds = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramId),
               ProgramYears = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramYear),
               ProgramTitles = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramTitle),
               ProgramTypes = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramType.ProgramType).Distinct(),
           };
```

Comment: Just the unique instances.  For example, 2010, 2011, 2012

Comment: The `where` clause in your example limits the possible years to 1, so couldn't you just assign a list containing `ProgramYear` to `ProgramYears`?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the `Distinct` operator?

```
(from SurveyProgramModel in surveyProgramRepository.Get()
 where SurveyProgramModel.ProgramYear == ProgramYear
 group SurveyProgramModel by SurveyProgramModel.ProgramTypeId)
.Distinct()
.Select(programTypeGroup => new ProgramTypeViewModel()
    {
        ProgramTypeIds = programTypeGroup.Key,
        ProgramIds = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramId),
        ProgramYears = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramYear),
        ProgramTitles = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramTitle),
        ProgramTypes = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramType.ProgramType).Distinct(),
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you just the distinct years like you want:

```
var years = surveyProgramRepository.Get()
           .Select(x => x.ProgramYear).Distinct();
```

or in case I'm misunderstanding the question and you want the distinct years *per group* in `ProgramYears` property, you can make the following change in your `Select` method:

```
...
ProgramYears = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramYear).Distinct(),
...
```

(but as noted in the comments, this wouldn't make sense because you've already filtered for a single year using `where`, so each group will have only one year in the `ProgramYears`)